# Should this tag have been [generated]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated) has 169 questions, but no wiki. The tag doesn't even make enough sense to me for me to be able to address whether it's suitable.

Should [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated) be burninated?

These are my answers to [the four burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. [Exclude folder in jacoco coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383380/exclude-folder-in-jacoco-coverage-report) talks about generated classes, while [Hibernate generating two different sequence Ids for PostgreSQL insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609461/hibernate-generating-two-different-sequence-ids-for-postgresql-insert) talks about sequence generated primary keys (and has the tag [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequence), suggesting someone thought [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated) was the right way to tag it).

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes. They're all about computer programming.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No.

Comment: this tag should be degenerated

Comment: What can be the tags that could be used instead of [generated]?